# Looking for the name of the spacetime interval with exponential

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, terminology, software

I have the following invariant: $$ds^2=e^{v(r,t)} c^2 dt^2 -r^2\left( d \theta^2 + sin^2(\theta) d \phi^2 \right) - e^{\lambda(r,t)}d r^2$$
for the centrally symmetric gravitational field. And I would like to know what is the name of it so I can define it in Maple 2020 with the package "Physics." Then I will be able to calculate the Christoffel symbols and all the rest.

Comment: That package doesn’t let you define any metric you want? If so, that’s lame.

Comment: Maple 2020 with the package "Physics."  the input is the metric?

Comment: I am sure that it is inside the "Physics" packages. There are hundreds of them. But the name would simplify the search. That is why I want to know the name of this particular metric.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a commonly accepted name for this metric. It's just a way of writing the most general form of centrally symmetric spacetime. Textbooks like Narlikar's and Cheng's use it as a starting point to derive the Schwarzschild metric and to introduce Birkhoff's theorem.

Comment: @Anyon You are right. In all the books that I looked up, they always use it for that. Sometimes, they move immediately to write the Schwarzschild metric. I think we can close this discussion. Thank you.